# Save chat room data in Application variable or DB, where is better?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

My application is  **Web App Chat Room** , it supports following features:

**1.Create/Join/Close room** 

**2.Send message in room (just live message, offline message might be supported in future)**

I have done logic for application, but I'm considering where to save chat room data (message,room information, and users in room) ? I see there are 2 options:

**1. Application variable**

**2. Using file or database**

-**What if I saved in Application variable:**

In case of there are 2000 rooms and 10000 users online, mean I have to persistence in Application variable (actually in RAM memory) information of 2000 rooms, more than 10000 message (text), these numbers might be increased by second if there are more users online in real time. and what's next ? I don't know what will happen to server, crash ? or my web app will be terminated ? whatever I don't want both results!

-**What if I saved in file or DB (i.e: SQL Server DB)** 

Because of web application, clients have to send request every 1 second to fetch data (messages and user list in room). So in case of there are 2000 rooms and 10000 users online, means they will make 10000 requests every 1 second to DB. I don't know what will happen to DB, there are a lot of connections and in EVERY 1 second, can DB still be alive to serve request ?

I don't know where saving is good now because both seem are bad solution :(. What is your opinion ? please give me some ideas for this ? thank so much!

Comment: "Because of web application, clients have to send request every 1 second"  Why is this?  This is your first problem.  You should be using something like BOSH or Comet.  Also, is there a good reason you're not using an off-the-shelf XMPP server?

Comment: My web is Asp.net MVC app, seem it only run on IIS server. I've not ever heard about BOSH or Comet or XMPP server before, Dose it run with IIS or can replace IIS to host my asp web chat ? Could you tell me more about them ?

Comment: Sure, XMPP is an open protocol for implementing chat (once known as "Jabber").  There are many XMPP servers out there that do all the legwork of implementing the protocol.  BOSH and Comet are Javascript technologies leveraging Ajax that facilitate bidirectional HTTP streams (HTTP is request/response whereas normal socket programming are long lived and allow repeated back and forth communication -- perfect for chatting).  For the Javascript side, I'd recommend http://blog.jwchat.org/jsjac/  For the server side see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software

Comment: Oh,It's really usefully resource! Have you ever developed Asp.net MVC web app with XMPP server and Ajax client lib for call back XMPP server? I don't have so much budget for a purchase server like lightstreamer server, and my asp.net web app need to serve up to more than 10000 connections, do u have any suggest for a free XMPP server which can integrate with asp.net mvc web app and can serve number of those connectons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database are made for this, to make a lot of requests, write and read data... they have a good optimize and not write everything down you know, they use cache and memory for make what you say.

I say use **database**, just take care to make a good design of your table. :) and delete old and not used data from your rooms time to time.